# I am getting only 2 as op for the below program

Tags: c

Please explain why I am getting output 2 here. My expected o/p is 5 or 7. Please throw some light. Thank you!

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef enum {a=3, b, c, d, j}e;

void f(e *e1) {
    printf("%ld", (int)*e1);
}

main(){
    e es;
    f(&es);
}
```

Comment: don't you wish to initialize es before passing it to f()?

Comment: if i intialize with 5, will get 5 as o/p. But why I am getting 2 as o/p without initialization?

Comment: Your `es` variable is uninitialised.

Comment: test.c: In function ‘f’:
test.c:6:5: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

Comment: so by default it initialize as 2 here??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't initialized `es`, so your program is just printing the random value that happens to be on the stack when the program runs.

You need to say something like:

```
e es = c;
```

That will give you the `5` output you seek.

Comment: so 2 is just only a random value? then why its getting printed always 2? it should take some other random value right?

Comment: It's not "random" as in "someone is doing the work needed to generate a correct random number which is hard to predict", it's random as in "there will be a value here which is impossible to predict, but it just is whatever happens to be there, nobody tries to affect in in any way".

Comment: @sree: unwind is right, but also, given different circumstances, your program will print different values. Build it with a different compiler, or on a different OS or CPU type, or run under [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR), or, or, or...

Comment: Thank you Warren Young and unwind for your thoughts.